# Applying `functools.lru_cache` to lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, lambda

So I made a recursive lambda in Python for the Fibonacci sequence. I used recursion because it was easiest to implement with lambda.

```
fib = lambda n: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1
```

Because using recursion, the same Fibonacci values were calculated many times, I thought using a cache decorator would help, and I knew that `functools.lru_cache` was an easy option.

I know you can't apply the decorator to the function using `@functools.lru_cache` to a lambda like a normal function, but when I tried this:

```
fib = functools.lru_cache((lambda n: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1), maxsize = None)
```

I got an error saying that `functools.lru_cache` wouldn't accept a function object as an argument.

```
>>> fib = functools.lru_cache((lambda n: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1), maxsize = None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    fib = functools.lru_cache((lambda n: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1), maxsize = None)
TypeError: lru_cache() got multiple values for argument 'maxsize'
```

I checked the docs, and it looks like `functools.lru_cache` only accepts a `maxsize` and a `typed` argument, which default to `128` and `False` respectively.

Is there a cleverer way to assign the decorator to the function rather than just defining the function without lambda and then applying the decorator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `fib = functools.lru_cache()(lambda n: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1)`

I believe that calling `lru_cache` returns a function, which takes a function and returns a function. To supply a max size, use `fib = functools.lru_cache(100)(lambda n: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1)`

Comment: This is because `lru_cache()` returns a decorator, but is not one itself; it's a decorator factory.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand why it worked at first, but after some fiddling around in the shell and the source code I understood: The function `lru_cache` returns another decorating function! Really clever!

Comment: @Cyphase Why did they make that kind of design decision anyway??

Comment: because that looks very natural when used as a decorator (which is the idea of this function). and how else could you pass additional arguments to the function?

Comment: @PythonGuy, what hiroprotagonist said :).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Oh yes, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

a small example with the most stupid function i could think of:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def identity(x):
    return x

identity2 = lru_cache(maxsize=32)(lambda x: x)
```

the first version is the decorator version where you can see the first agument of `lru_cache`. from there it is easy to see how to get the syntax for a lambda expression right.